# Using MWArray in .NET 6 Application throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, .net-6.0

In my .NET 6 WPF Application i try to reference the MWArray.dll provided by Mathworks to access a dll i build with the MATLAB2022b Library compiler.

Path of MWArray.dll:
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2022b\toolbox\dotnetbuilder\bin\win64\netstandard2.0\MWArray.dll

When trying to instanciate my dll:

```
this.matLibrary = new MatLabInterface.MatlabLibrary();
```

the application crashes with the following error message:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MatLabInterface.MatlabLibrary' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(QCallModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctorWithParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType)
   at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MatLabInterface.MatlabLibrary..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MatLabInterface.MatlabLibrary..ctor()
```

Has anyone ever experienced the same issue?

As a note: This Dll worked with my Framework 4.7.0 Version of the same program.
I´m currently trying to migrate to .NET6

I already tried the v4.0 MWArray too.

What I also tried or did was to enable the Flag in the MatLab Library compiler to compile the DLL for .NET 5.0
[MATLAB Library Compiler Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euCAm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Due to running from a WindowsFormsApp some black magic happens and this error is thrown. When loading or creating the Matlab Object before loading the WindowsFormsApp and pasing it to the App everything works fine....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).